# How to get run elapsed time for a gazebo simulation

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How to compute  run elapsed time for a gazebo simulation in c++.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/223089/how-to-get-run-elapsed-time-for-a-gazebo-simulation/) by [languyen](https://answers.ros.org/users/25423/languyen/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-12-25

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Gazebo publishes time on the `/clock` topic  as described [here](http://wiki.ros.org/Clock#Using_Simulation_Time_from_the_.2BAC8-clock_Topic). This has the nice side-effect that you can subscribe to it and directly read the elapsed simulation time from it.

---

Originally posted by [Stefan Kohlbrecher](https://answers.ros.org/users/57/stefan-kohlbrecher/) with karma: 24361 on 2015-12-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0